# LMDB: Rolling back transactions without rolling back everything

Tags: database, lmdb

I have an application that uses LMDB.  If multiple processes need to write to the database, only one will be allowed to run at a time and the rest block.  Because of this, I want to rewrite the application to use a client-server model.

If the application is written to use a client-server model, the server can manage the writes and the other processes won't block.  However, if a client encounters an error and has to roll back its transaction, how can it roll back its data without rolling back what the other clients have written?

I've looked at nested transactions, but write transactions may only have one nested transaction.  So while a client can write its data to a nested transaction and roll it back if an error occurs, only one client will be able to run at a time.  So while that solves the rollback problem, we're back to the problem that only one client can write at a time.

I've also taken a look at the MDB_NOLOCK option, which causes LMDB to not stop you from creating multiple write transactions.  When you try to commit any transaction but the first one, it will return an error.  Maybe the clients can pool their writes into their own transactions and when they're ready to commit, the server will dump the entries into the first write transaction, but that is hacky and I'm certain that is NOT what the developers intended it to be used for.

The only other solution I can think of is to keep clients in a separate database, which undoes the entire purpose of switching to a client-server model.

Are there any other ways to allow different processes to write to the database, while being able to roll back one client's data without rolling back everything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to the challenge you pose.

One can nest write transactions arbitrarily deep, but as you say that doesn't help you achieve better throughput because you'll still be limited to one thread for that write transaction.   So for most intents and purposes, if you use LMDB as it was designed to be used, you're only going to have one thread doing write operations on the database.

You asked how you can abort someone's transaction without rolling back the txn of others.  This is largely not an issue because, as mentioned above, you will have only one write transaction active at at time.   If you commit at the end of the request and start a new transaction at the beginning of the next request, your write transactions will not overlap.   Once you commit the first transaction, you'll not be able to abort it, but if your client informs the server to abort the request before it's committed, your server can abort it.  And when it aborts, the database state will resort to the state it was in when that transaction was started.  It will not lose any other transactions and not lose the changes created by other requests.

As you point out, you could batch some of the write requests in to a single write txn.  You could process some of those write requests in other threads, but **all** LMDB API calls must still be done in the original thread. And if you try to dedicate a thread to each request to achieve some parallelism, you'll still need to ensure that the requests are mutually compatible and don't interfere with each other.  And if one of those requests runs in to trouble, you'll have to abort the transaction and probably restart the transaction.  When you restart the transactions, you'll probably only include the requests that did not run in to trouble. --  This is all possible, but only you have enough knowledge about your application to know if this would improve performance much and be worth your effort.